How to generate random orthonormal matrices following linear constraints?
I know how I can sample orthonormal matrices from the Haar distribution, but is there any way I can modify this procedure to sample from the set of matrices which follow certain predefined linear equalities?
For example, the matrix $W$ I generate should transform the vector $b$ to $a$:
$a = Wb$
I can sample $n$ different $W_i$, and find which linear combination of $W_ib$ is closest to $a$, and use those regression coefficients to generate my final $W$, but I am looking for a method more efficient than this. I also find it hard to expand this method to the case where I need to adhere to multiple linear equalities.

Is there any way I can use Householder transforms? I would prefer if the matrices I generate are not rank-1 perturbations to the identity matrix if possible.

You can left-compose with a rotation $O$ to assume $a = e_1$; this $O$ can be constructed using the Gram-Schmidt process. Select $n$ rows for $OW$ perpendicular to $b$, i.e. sample the $b^\bot$ space, and add $b^T/\|b\|^2$ to the first row. Then left-multiply with the inverse rotation $O^{-1}$ to recover $W$.

Can I extend this to the case where I need to satisfy multiple linear equalities this way:
In this case, should my first few rows be the result of the Gram-Schmidt process on my $b_i$s, the rest of the rows should be perpendicular to all my $b_i$s?
